# Binding custom log4j2 wrapper with slf4j

Tags: log4j2, slf4j

I am writing a custom wrapper over log4j2. Using https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html#CustomLoggers

The requirement was to choose the appender based on the object type being logged. The approach I am thinking was to extend the log4j2 logger and override log methods(like info), In those methods, check the object type and call the required appender.

Now I want my application to use slf4j facade instead of log4j2 directly. Need help on how to bind my custom log4j2 wrapper to slf4j, with less effort :)

One option I am thinking(haven't tried yet) is to refer my customlogger wrapper in log4j-slf4j-impl and generate jar and use the same in application,
https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/f838bd6f42ea104e692e9e2227dcc54283a41901/log4j-slf4j18-impl/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/slf4j/Log4jLogger.java

- Do we have any better approach to solve this problem?

Comment: This might be helpful, I've built some applications using Ninja Framework, and I know they use sl4j as their logging solution. You might take a look at their logging source for ideas on how they've implemented it.  http://www.ninjaframework.org/documentation/logging.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose an Appender based on an object type one way to do it is to use Log4j 2's [RoutingAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender). The RoutingAppender may be configured with either a pattern or a Script. The pattern is used to extract something from the log event. That value is then matched against the configured options from which a "route" to an Appender is chosen. When using a Script the script returns the name of the "route" to use.